# javascript: button to toggle a timed color change on and off

Tags: javascript

I have a function that allows a user to enter their preferred timing frequency (they do so via a textbox) to change the background color of all the divs on the page to randomly generated colors.  That works a charm.

**However**, I need to include a button that onClick will toggle the timed color change on and off (and on when clicked and off when clicked ad nauseam).  I've no idea how to do this.

I'm including below the code that works to change the div colors when a user enters a frequency in the textbox:

```
var yourTiming = document.forms["myForm"]["timing"].value;

   function goRandom() {

   var myTiming = setInterval(colourMe, yourTiming);
}

function colourMe() {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor =
            '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor =
            '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.getElementById("div3").style.backgroundColor =
            '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.getElementById("div4").style.backgroundColor =
            '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

I've no idea how to create a function that will, when the user clicks a button, toggle the timed color change on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 from the MDN documentation seems to demonstrate pretty much what you're trying to achieve: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Hey Kamik thanks but it doesn't do the trick.  I need the button to on first click stop (clearInterval) then on the next click start (go back to the goRandom function that had the setInterval) then stop, then start etc.